# SQL Server - Create temp table if doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

In my SQL Server 2012 environment, I've created a series of stored procedures that pass pre-existing temporary tables among themselves (I have tried different architectures here, but wasn't able to bypass this due to the nature of the requirements / procedures).

What I'm trying to do is to, within a stored procedure check if a temporary table has already been created and, if not, to create it.

My current SQL looks as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE #MyTable
    (
        Col1 INT,
        Col2 VARCHAR(10)
        ...
    );
```

But when I try and run it **when the table already exists**, I get the error message

> There is already an object named '#MyTable' in the database

So it seems it doesn't simply ignore those lines within the If statement.

Is there a way to accomplish this - create a temp table if it doesn't already exist, otherwise, use the one already in memory?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

For whatever reason, following @RaduGheorghiu's suggestion from the comments, I found out that the system creates a temporary table with a name along the lines of `dbo.#MyTable________________________________________________0000000001B1`

Is that why I can't find it? Is there any way to change that? This is new to me....

Comment: Can you show the full code? As far as I know, temporary tables are session-specific and are limited to a stored procedure scope (cannot be seen outside of the same stored procedure). Also can you just expand the `System Databases->TempDB->Temporary Tables` tree in Object explorer and see if there is a `#MyTable` table existing before running the procedure?

Comment: Also, sharing data between stored procedures isn't done with a "intermediate-temporary-table". You would use `OUTPUT` objects and input parameters that are of a table type .

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, If you simply were to put this code into a session window and, before it, simply create the temp table, you'll get the error I'm referring to - The issue I'm having is that the If statement doesn't seem to make a difference, if the temp table exists beforehand, you get an error whereas I wouldn't expect that to happen

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, as for the OUTPUT objects, I'm not sure I understand what you mean - It is pretty common practice to have a stored procedure write to a `#TempTable` that was created before the stored proc was called, no?

Comment: I'm really sorry but I can't reproduce your problem. I've ran `create table #MyTable (col1 int);` then ran `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NULL
        CREATE TABLE #MyTable
            (
                Col1 INT
            );` multiple times and I don't get any error.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, I just posted an update - Thanks to your suggestion of looking at the Temporary Tables, I found that the system creates a table with a different name.... Any thoughts??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136875/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-john-bustos).

Comment: They had some similar issue here ... http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/08/21/SQL-Server-2005-temporary-tables-bug-feature-or-expected-behavior.aspx

Comment: @manderson, that did it!! - I had to use the `GO` statement and then everything worked.... Please post this as an answer, it fixed the problem which appears to be a SQL Server bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the link here, http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/08/21/SQL-Server-2005-temporary-tables-bug-feature-or-expected-behavior.aspx

It seems as though you need to use the GO statement.

Comment: This answer may solve the issue, but the chat thread [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136875/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-john-bustos) referenced in the question comments was more helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You meant to use IS NOT NULL i think... this is commonly used to clear temp tables so you don't get the error you mentioned in your OP.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTable
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    Col1 INT,
    Col2 VARCHAR(10)
);
```

The big difference is the `DROP TABLE` statement after you do your logical check. Also, creating your table without filling data doesn't make it `NULL`

```
DROP TABLE #MyTable

CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    Col1 INT,
    Col2 VARCHAR(10)
);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL 
SELECT 1
```

Comment: @JohnBustos if it does exists, would you expect it to have data in it already?

Comment: Yes, I'd just want to insert extra rows - That's what I want it for....

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your actions in a `begin...end` block:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#MyTable') is null
begin
  create table #MyTable (
     Col1 int
   , Col2 varchar(10)
  );
end
```

Comment: Tried this - Still no dice :/

Comment: I also posted an update to my question - seems the DB is doing somethign different when I create the temp table. When I examine it, I see the table created is named `dbo.#MyTable________________________________________________0000000001B1` for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

This seems odd, but it works when I try it

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NULL) --check if it exists
  BEGIN
    IF(1 = 0)--this will never actually run, but it tricks the parser into allowing the CREATE to run
        DROP TABLE #Test;

    PRINT 'Create table';

    CREATE TABLE #Test
    (
        ID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );
  END

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Test))
    INSERT INTO #Test(ID)
    VALUES(1);

SELECT *
FROM #Test;

--Try dropping the table and test again
--DROP TABLE #Test;
```