# Check if Temporal Table Exisits

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I've created a temporable table, how can i verify with a script that it has been added. So i'm trying to created a script, to create the temporal table if it has not already created. The if doesn't work

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[CarHistory]') IS NULL) 
BEGIN
Print 'Add Temporal table to Car table'

Alter table Car 
ADD SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
SysEndTime  DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
             PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime, EndTime)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Car SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE=dbo.CarHistory));

END
```

But i get this error 
Msg 13597, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
Temporal SYSTEM_TIME period is already defined on table 'dbo.Car' because i have already added it.

Comment: check if column SYSTEM_TIME exists

Comment: Look at this answer from the other day... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511328/sql-server-create-temp-table-if-doesnt-exist/42512671?noredirect=1#comment72162698_42512671

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to `temporal_type` column in [sys.tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx).

Below are the total values

**temporal_type column :**

0 = NON_TEMPORAL_TABLE
1 = HISTORY_TABLE
2 = SYSTEM_VERSIONED_TEMPORAL_TABLE

you can use something like below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.table WHERE name = 'Car' AND temporal_type = 2)
BEGIN
        ...
END
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 separate things that are done to make a table Temporal, adding the time period, and setting the versioning = on for the table.  Jovan's answer checks for the table being temporal, but does NOT check to see if the period is associated to the table.  It is true that if the table is Temporal, it will have the time period, but if it is not Temporal, it MIGHT still have the time period.

Also keep in mind that if doing this in an if statement, the preparation of the statement will fail trying to add the period, even though it would not execute due to the if statement, so you need to make that one dynamic sql.  This will check if a table has the period, and add it if needed (assuming you already added and set values for columns SysStartTime, SysEndTime), then also check to see if the table is Temporal, and make it Temporal if it is not.

```
--check to see if the time period is added to this table already, and add if needed.
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.periods where object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName'))
begin
    --add time period for table
    EXEC sp_executesql 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)';
END 
    
    
--see if this table is not already temporal, if not make it so
IF EXISTS (SELECT temporal_type
        FROM   sys.tables
        WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[TableName]', 'u') 
        AND temporal_type = 0)
BEGIN           
    --turn versioning on
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [data].[TableName_Hist], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = OFF));
END
```