# Conditionally Create Temp Table in SQL from Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, odbc, temp-tables

In a large set of queries, I'm trying to create a temp table in SQL, if it doesn't already exist.  Obviously, you could remove the 2nd `CREATE TABLE` statement.  However, the queries I'm building are dynamic and may, or may not, have the 1st `CREATE TABLE` statement present.

I can get the following sample/test query to work in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  It was created with help from [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511328/sql-server-create-temp-table-if-doesnt-exist/42512671#comment120257712_42512671)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp_sample;
CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    datetime DATETIME,
    location VARCHAR(255)
);
GO 
    
INSERT INTO #temp_sample (id, datetime, location)
VALUES ('ABC', '2021-06-04 15:52:44', 'PENNSYLVANIA'),('123', '2021-06-04 15:52:49', 'PENNSYLVANIA');

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_sample') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (
            id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            datetime DATETIME,
            location VARCHAR(255)
        );
    END
ELSE 
    PRINT '#temp_sample already exists... skipping'
GO

SELECT * FROM #temp_sample
```

WHEN I run the following code in the same database, but using `pandas.io.sql.read_sql` and `pypyodbc` I get the accompanying traceback:

```py
import pypyodbc
import pandas.io.sql as psql

connection_string = 'DSN=dsn_name;UID=username;PWD=password;app=app_name;'
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)
temp_db_query = '''
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
       
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp_sample;
    CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (
        id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        datetime DATETIME,
        location VARCHAR(255)
    );
    GO

    INSERT INTO #temp_sample (id, datetime, location)
    VALUES ('ABC', '2021-06-04 15:52:44', 'PENNSYLVANIA'),('123', '2021-06-04 15:52:49', 'PENNSYLVANIA');

    IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_sample') IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (
                id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                datetime DATETIME,
                location VARCHAR(255)
            );
        END
    ELSE
        PRINT '#temp_sample already exists... skipping'
    GO

    SELECT * FROM #temp_sample
'''

df = psql.read_sql(temp_db_query, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1595, in execute 
        cur.execute(*args)
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1626, in execute 
        self.execdirect(query_string)
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1652, in execdirect 
        check_success(self, ret)
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
        ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 975, in ctrl_err
        raise ProgrammingError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named '#temp_sample' in the database.")
```

Can someone help me get the query to work using `pandas.io.sql.read_sql`?  I'm open to switching to another odbc package like `pyodbc`, `turbodbc`, etc.

### ======= UPDATE ========

Based on one of the comments, I tried changing the logic in the `IF` statement because it appears that, when using ODBC, it's getting flagged as TRUE.  This version also works in MSSMS, but gives me the same error in Python.  Is there another version that works?

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#temp_sample%')
        PRINT '#temp_sample already exists... skipping'
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (
                id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                datetime DATETIME,
                location VARCHAR(255)
            );
        END
    GO
```

Comment: Can you add your python code to  your question?

Comment: I added the python code to the question as requested.

Comment: remove all `GO`statements. Also, I don't see a use case where `IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_sample') IS NULL)`  test TRUE in SQL, it might be testing FALSE via ODBC

Comment: @Horaciux, I tried to remove all of the `GO` statements and got the same result.  The `IF` statement not returning TRUE in ODBC is interesting though, If it was FALSE though it shouldn't be trying to `CREATE` the table a second time...

Answer (score 0):

This is a batch compilation error.  When you remove the `GO`, which you must to to get this to compile, then there are two `CREATE TABLE` statements for the same temp table, which won't parse and compile.  EG this batch generates the same error:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (id int)
if 1=0
begin
  CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (id int)
end
```

To fix, just remove the second `CREATE TABLE`, as it's unnecessary anyway.  EG

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
   
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp_sample;
CREATE TABLE #temp_sample (
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    datetime DATETIME,
    location VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO #temp_sample (id, datetime, location)
VALUES ('ABC', '2021-06-04 15:52:44', 'PENNSYLVANIA'),('123', '2021-06-04 15:52:49', 'PENNSYLVANIA');

SELECT * FROM #temp_sample
```

Comment: This answer does not work for me.  I've mentioned above that the sample query in the question is actually just a part of a much larger (dynamically generated) query.  Just removing the second `CREATE TABLE` is not a viable solution in this case.  For this case, I need to have the table present if it's created, or not, prior to the `IF` statement.

Comment: Then you'll have to run the logic in separate batches, just like SSMS does when you have `GO` in a script.